# Gracefully degrade text-overflow CSS property

Tags: html, internet-explorer, css, graceful-degradation

I'm using the `text-overflow` CSS property to get the ellipse effect, which I believe is only supported in IE as of now. My question is, I'm not looking for a work around to get it to work in Firefox, rather I am looking for a solution that gracefully degrades in other browsers instead of truncating the text abruptly. So, instead of ellipses in Firefox, it would fallback to a normal text wrap.

Not sure if this is possible considering `text-overflow` is dependent on both the `overflow` and `white-space` properties...

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: To help us (by that I mean: me) understand, can you provide a [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/) showing `text-overflow` working normally in supported browsers, and how it `"truncates the text abruptly"` in Firefox?

Comment: @thirtydot: I'd imagine it's something like this: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HJmZP/), wherein the first `div` has `text-overflow: hidden;` and the second has merely the `overflow: hidden;` property.

Comment: Actually ellipses works in Safari/Chrome as well.  Firefox is the odd man out here.  The real issue is that you don't have font-metrics available in any browser.  Your best bet would be to drop an opaque layer on top of the text in firefox (positioned bottom-right)... but you'll wind up with with half-hidden letters.  If you post a fiddle or something with your base code, somebody might craft something up.

Comment: @david Thomas - I think yo mean `text-overflow:ellipses` vs. `text-overflow:hidden`.

Comment: David, that's exactly the type of behavior I am referring to.

Comment: @John, there's a typo in your `text-overflow` (it's `ellipsis`). Otherwise, no: `text-overflow` is automatically `hidden` if the containing element's `overflow` is set to `hidden`. Though, to be honest, it works either way.

Comment: @David - Yes, sorry.  Got it confused with the plural in my own head.

Comment: @John, not a problem at all :)

Comment: @MrRay - Start something and somebody will probably finish it for you.  It is a bit too involved and requires too many assumptions to craft from wholecloth.  However, my recommendation is to not do it.  There isn't a 'good' solution.  : )

Answer (score 1):

For IE, Safari, Chrome (and other Webkit browsers) and the latest versions of Opera, the `text-overflow` property is already supported. If you need support for older versions of Opera (pre-11.0), you can use the prefixed property, like this:

```
.ellipsis {
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Firefox (and other Gecko-based browsers) don't support the text-overflow property at all, which is disappointing because it's actually quite useful. But for Firefox, you can use some JavaScript to create the ellipsis. You can find a solution using JQuery [HERE](http://devongovett.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/text-overflow-ellipsis-for-firefox-via-jquery/). The developer provides a demo program on his site. It's not as well implemented as a pure CSS solution, and obviously doesn't work when JS is turned off, but it's the closest you can get at this time with Firefox.

HTH.

Comment: Thank @KarlNicoll. I was really hoping to stay away from a javascript solution, but there may be no way around it until Firefox comes around and supports it.

Comment: Actually it's already added in Firefox, but not sure when it will be in a public build. Probably in Firefox 6.

Comment: @Lea Verou - That's great news, I wasn't aware it was even being worked on. The MDC documentation on `text-overflow` just says "Unimplemented".

Comment: I can confirm it's supposed to be Firefox 6, see: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=312156

Comment: @thirtydot - Thanks for the information, that's good to know, although it is a little disconcerting that it's been on BZ for nearly 5 years :-P